# Get current touch location anytime in Cocos2d for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I have been using the following method to detect when a touch began and what the location is:

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];

    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    return YES;
}
```

But I would also like to know how to get the current location anytime of my touch if my finger is still on the screen. Anyone know how? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'll post this as an answer in a bit I think, but this is what I did:

I just kept converting a variable in a ccTime method defined outside of all my methods:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
heroMoveEndLoc = [self convertToNodeSpace:heroMoveEndLoc];
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having, even with ccTouchMoved, I need to move my touch to make the event happen.

Comment: So, you want to generate events continuously while your finger is still pressed down on the same location?

Comment: Yeah it sounds weird but the nodespace actually changes because a map scrolls to your touch location, so even if you have your finger in the same place, the touch will be a different location in nodespace if it scrolls.

Comment: So then you may want to edit your question to include the nodespace/scrolling info/code.  From the way it's worded now, it's hard to understand how to help.  EDIT, sorry I see that you did that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this...

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    x_point = location.x;
    y_point  = location.y;
    [self schedule:@selector(updateFunction)];
}

-(void)updateFunction
{
    NSLog(@"Location is %0.02f %0.02f",x_point,y_point);
}
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self unschedule:@selector(updateFunction)];

}
```

Comment: Thanks... I was beginning to just have more and more problems doing it my own way. I'm going to see if this will work for me and give you an update.

Comment: Okay I think this works. Problem was is that I needed to make my touch location global so other things could access it. I was also conversion the sprites end location to node space over and over.