# Cocos2d coordinate system

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, drawing

in cocos2d, the coordinate system is pretty straightforward.. bottom left is (0,0).
whenever i set the position of anything it's fine.

lets say a layer is TouchEnabled.

when im setting the position of my sprite, it's fine..

```
[crab setPosition:ccp(20, 50)];
```

but if i get the x and y coordinate of a touch (and assume i clicked on the sprite..):

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches began!");
    NSArray *touchArray = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch *one = [touchArray objectAtIndex:0];
    pointOne = [one locationInView:[one view]];
    CCLOG(@"points are: %f and %f", pointOne.x, pointOne.y );
}
```

the y coordinate is the opposite of what cocos2d's coordinate system suggests as the y increases from top to bottom !

so im assuming the coordinate system of the view is different than mac's coord system.. which is quite counter intuitive.. is that correct?

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL uses a (0, 0) of bottom left while iOS and therefore UIKit which handles the touches use top left as (0, 0). It is easy to convert your point over, you just have to remember to do it.

The correct method on cocos2d 2.0 is

```
CGPoint uiKitPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
CGPoint cocos2dPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:uiKitPoint];
```

Answer (score 1):

This cocos2d tutorial might help you

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/06/08/Cocos2D-HTML-Tutorial-3All-about-sprites-and-positioning.aspx

But generally speaking in cocos2d point (0,0) is the left corner of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2D already can handle this for you. The CCDirector has some methods for this. Please, take a look at this older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953772/get-current-touch-location-anytime-in-cocos2d-for-iphone).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, for most graphics related applications, there is a tendency to place (0, 0) at the lower-left (and this is the case with the Mac) - where as on iOS, it's positioned at the top-left as you've noticed.

When you're handling input with Cocos, you can quickly convert it over by using the  **convertTouchToNodeSpace** method (at least with 1.x - I've not played with 2.0 enough - but I believe it's **convertToNodeSpace** there from a quick documentation check). This will then do the necessary transformations to give you the right coordinate.

(NB: I need to dig up some of my other code to double check - but I can't remember off the top of my head whether this counts of camera offsets as well - I'll edit when I can get to my demo code & confirm.)

Answer (score 0):

The Touches come from UIKit which top left is (0,0) so you need to convert it to the coordinate system of cocos2d before handling with this data.

There is

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL];
```

For UIkit -> cocos2d

Comment: convertToNodeSpace converts a point that is not in the current nodes coordinate system to itself. For instance a world coordinate (but still in openGL format) to the nodes coordinate system.

Comment: Updates my answer by adding the converttogl method

Comment: It is still incorrect. Convert to node space is not for uikit points